# Will a Schengen visa allow an Indian citizen to Mexico?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, mexico

I am an Indian citizen having a valid multiple entry Schengen visa and want to travel from Delhi to Mexico via Amsterdam. I will stay in Mexico for 3 days & will head towards Paris. Do I need a Mexican visa or only a Schengen visa?

Answer (score 1):

following the info in Mexican Consulate in SFO, the Schengen visa allows you to enter Mexico.

> With the purpose of facilitating and promoting travel to Mexico,
>   effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their
>   nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT
>   required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a valid (non-expired)
>   Visa or Permanent Residence of any of this countries: United States of
>   America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or Schengen area (European
>   Union).

Source: [Department of the Consulate General of México in San Francisco](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico)

In spanish:

> b)  Visa válida y vigente de Canadá, de los Estados Unidos de América,
>   Japón, el Reino Unido de la Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte o
>   cualquiera de los países que integran el Espacio Schengen.

Source: [Países y regiones que requieren visa para viajar a México](http://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/)

Answer (score 1):

Per Timatic, the database used by Airlines:

> Passengers with a valid visa issued by Canada, Japan, USA,
>     United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State for
>     a maximum stay of 180 days¨

So no, you do **not** need a visa